# How do I query the alignment/stride for an SSBO struct?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4, shader-storage-buffer

I'm not sure which structure layout is most suited for my application: `shared`, `packed`,`std140`, `std430`. I'm not asking for an explanation of each, that information is easy to find, it's just hard to figure out the impact each will have on vendor compatibility/performance. If `shared` is the default, I'm suspecting that's a good starting point.

From what I can gather, I have to query the alignment/offsets when using `shared` or `packed`, because it's implementation specific.

What's the API for for querying it? Is there some parameter I pass to `glGetShaderiv` while the compute shader is bound, that lets me figure out the alignments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`glGetProgramInterface`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInterface.xhtml) with the parameter `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK` to get the number of the
[Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) and the maximum name length.
The maximum name length of the buffer variables can be get from the program interface `GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE`:

```cpp
GLuint prog_obj; // shader program object
```

```cpp
GLint no_of, ssbo_max_len, var_max_len;
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES, &no_of);
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, GL_MAX_NAME_LENGTH, &ssbo_max_len);
glGetProgramInterfaceiv(prog_obj, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, GL_MAX_NAME_LENGTH, &var_max_len);
```

The name of the SSBO can be get by [`glGetProgramResourceName`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramResourceName.xhtml) and a resource index by [`glGetProgramResourceIndex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramResourceIndex.xhtml):

```cpp
std::vector< GLchar >name( max_len );
for( int i_resource = 0; i_resource < no_of; i_resource++ ) {

    // get name of the shader storage block
    GLsizei strLength;
    glGetProgramResourceName(
        prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, i_resource, ssbo_max_len, &strLength, name.data());

    // get resource index of the shader storage block
    GLint resInx = glGetProgramResourceIndex(prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, name.data());

    // [...]
}
```

Data of the shader storage block can be retrieved by [`glGetProgramResource`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramResource). See also [Program Introspection](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection).

Get the number of of buffer variables and its indices from program interface and `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK` and the shader storage block resource `resInx`:

```cpp
for( int i_resource = 0; i_resource < no_of; i_resource++ ) {

    // [...]

    GLint resInx = ...

    // get number of the buffer variables in the shader storage block
    GLenum prop = GL_NUM_ACTIVE_VARIABLES;
    GLint num_var;
    glGetProgramResourceiv(
        prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, resInx, 1, &prop,
        1, nullptr, &num_var);

    // get resource indices of the buffer variables
    std::vector<GLint> vars(num_var);
    prop = GL_ACTIVE_VARIABLES;
    glGetProgramResourceiv(
        prog_obj, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, resInx,
        1, &prop, (GLsizei)vars.size(), nullptr, vars.data());

    // [...]
}
```

Get the offsets of the buffer variables, in basic machine units, relative to the base of buffer and its names from the program interface `GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE` and the resource indices `vars[]`:

```cpp
for( int i_resource = 0; i_resource < no_of; i_resource++ ) {

    // [...]

    std::vector<GLint> offsets(num_var);
    std::vector<std::string> var_names(num_var);
    for (GLint i = 0; i < num_var; i++) {

        // get offset of buffer variable relative to SSBO
        GLenum prop = GL_OFFSET;
        glGetProgramResourceiv(
            prog_obj, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, vars[i],
            1, &prop, (GLsizei)offsets.size(), nullptr, &offsets[i]);

        // get name of buffer variable
        std::vector<GLchar>var_name(var_max_len);
        GLsizei strLength;
        glGetProgramResourceName(
            prog_obj, GL_BUFFER_VARIABLE, vars[i], 
            var_max_len, &strLength, var_name.data());
        var_names[i] = var_name.data();
    }

    // [...]
}
```

See also [`ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object.txt)